# audiokit recorder records the first time and doesn't record again the 2nd time

Tags: swift, audiokit

it's my first time using audioKit. great framework by the way

I am able to record, works beautifully.

```
 func prepareToAKrecord() {
        // Setup microphone and reverb
               mic = engine.input
               reverb = Reverb(mic)
                reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.mediumRoom) //large hall etc
               engine.output = reverb

        do {

            // Check if the recorder is already recording
                    if recorder?.isRecording == true {
                        print("Recorder is already recording. Attempting to stop before reinitializing.")
                        recorder?.stop()
                    }
            

                    // Reset the recorder if it exists
                    if let existingRecorder = recorder {
                        try existingRecorder.reset()
                        print("Recorder reset successfully.")
                    }
            recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: reverb, shouldCleanupRecordings: true)
             try self.engine.start()
             try self.recorder!.record()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create recorder: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
```

then I stop it

```
    func stopAKRecordingAndSave() {
        self.isRecording = false
        
       
        //recorder!.stop()
        recorder.stop()
        engine.stop()
        
        if let recordedAudioFile = recorder!.audioFile {
            self.voiceURL = recordedAudioFile.url
            print("Recording saved to: \(self.voiceURL!)")
            //dec-4
            self.mergeVoiceSong() // Merge this voice reverb and backing track
            //self.merging = false
        } else {
            print("Failed to get the recorded audio file")
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false,forKey: "newSearch")

    }
```

but if I try to start the engine and record again doesn't work, not even if I do a record.reset()

am I missing an special method to clear the bus? should I keep the engine running and just reset?

I get a bunch of warnings the 2nd time I try recording

[image]

Comment: Yes, keep the engine running and also try it without the reverb. Think how your  node chain looks in the various conditions of your app.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to know if audiokit engine is runnning? .isrunning doesn't exist

Comment: yes that was the issue, with audiokit there is no need to stop the engine, or even inputs/reverbs, simpy just start it once (including reverb etc) and stop/record the recorder as needed, very simple but it took me 2 days of struggling, thanks to audiokit for making this so simple,  so simple that we engineers tend to overcomplicate implementations lol. if you pst it as answer I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the engine running and try it without the reverb. As long as you don't stop the engine and it doesn't throw an error, it is running.

Think how your node chain looks in the various conditions of your app.

https://www.audiokit.io/AudioKit/documentation/audiokit/audioengine
https://www.audiokit.io/AudioKit/documentation/audiokit/node